# How to fix the error message that says "this version of Cosmos SDK is no longer supported" when running starport scaffold commands?

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk, starport

Using starport version v0.17.1 darwin/amd64 -build date: 2021-07-27T13:10:21Z, the starport scaffold commands gives an error saying "this version of Cosmos SDK is no longer supported"

Answer (score 0):

This error only occurs when you are trying to `starport chain serve` a chain scaffolded with SDK `v0.39.x`. Also check if you are using the latest go version by running `go version` :)